# Creating view for power users with schemabinding? (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, database

When creating views, what options do we have in terms of giving power users the ability for simple queries against the view?

I understand that adding WITH SCHEMABINDING is after the view name when creating which bounds the schema to the database objects referencing the view.

So for example,

```
CREATE VIEW TestView WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT * FROM Table1
```

Is there a hint or something that we can put right before the 'WITH SCHEMABINDING' to give power users the option for simple queries?

For example:
    CREATE VIEW TestView _____ WITH SCHEMABINDING
    AS
    SELECT * FROM Table1

I am currently studying for my SQL Server exam and this is a question that I came upon with a practice test and I've been trying to figure out the answer but can't find anything online from Microsoft, etc.

Comment: Why would adding a hint to a view allow power users to create/modify simple queries? Your question isn't making much sense to me as you seem to be discussing security for power users but using a view definition to conduct security distribution. Here is the full syntax for `create/alter view` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Is there a hint or something that we can put right before the 'WITH SCHEMABINDING' to give power users the option for simple queries?*

**No.** There are just 3 "view attributes" (see below)

```
-- Syntax for SQL Server and Azure SQL Database  

CREATE [ OR ALTER ] VIEW [ schema_name . ] view_name [ (column [ ,...n ] ) ]   
[ WITH <view_attribute> [ ,...n ] ]   
AS select_statement   
[ WITH CHECK OPTION ]   
[ ; ]  

<view_attribute> ::=   
{  
    [ ENCRYPTION ]  
    [ SCHEMABINDING ]  
    [ VIEW_METADATA ]       
}
```

see: [CREATE VIEW (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql)